# SQL sort ascending but null values descending

Tags: sql-server, sorting, sql-server-2012

Table has a nullable ContactDate field. I want to sort these records so that non-null values come first in ascending order and then null values are sorted after non-nullable values.

```
Select * from myTable Order by ContactDate ASC
```

returns following

```
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
2015-07-27 10:00:00.000
2015-07-29 10:00:00.000
```

then,

```
Select * from myTable Order by ContactDate DESC
```

returns following

```
2015-07-29 10:00:00.000
2015-07-27 10:00:00.000
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

But I need it like this:

```
2015-07-27 10:00:00.000 -- asc
2015-07-29 10:00:00.000 -- asc
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

Using MS SQL Server 2012

Comment: Try `ORDER BY ContactDate ASC NULLS LAST`. That works in postgresql, not sure about sql-server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `case` statement in `order by`.

**Query**

```
select * from myTable
order by case when ContactDate is null then 1
else 0 end,ContactDate;
```

[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c33ba/1)

Comment: Why downvote?? What's wrong with my query?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ISNULL()` to convert the NULL values to 9999-12-31 and then `order by` ContactDate:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
ORDER BY ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR, ContactDate), '9999-12-31') ASC
```